# How do I send this json request body from angular using http client post method?

Tags: angular

This is Postman example of how request body looks like
I am sending query_string to flask backend and it return list of tweets.
[image: Postman Image]

Now I want to send post request from angular application using http client post method

searchTerm is the query_string

```
import { GoogleResponse } from './components/GoogleResponse.model';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { Injectable, Query } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { solr_Response } from './components/solr_response.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {

  

  private url: string = '3.22.175.82:5000/queryresult';



  /*     solr url     */


  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * 
   * @param searchTerm 
   * @returns 
   */
  getSearchData(searchTerm: string): Observable<any> {

    
    
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, searchTerm);
  
  }



}
```

I am simply sending an string as request body but it's giving me errors my guess is the body needs to be in a object or simply string is enough.
But I am getting this errors
[image]

Comment: shouldn't url start with http:// or https://?

Comment: In your error response, url field shows an incorrect URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @vicatcu, `url` should by a valid URL starting with http:// or https://. In addition, your endpoint expects an object `{ "query_string": "..." }`. Therefore it should be something like this:

```
private url = 'http://3.22.175.82:5000/queryresult';

...

getSearchData(searchTerm: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post(this.url, { query_string: searchTerm });
}
```